# How do I install Adobe Reader 9 on Ubuntu 10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, adobe-reader

I'm trying to install Adobe Reader 9 on Ubuntu 10.  I'd be happiest to `apt-get install` something, but I'm not picky.  I downloaded a file from the web site, but neither I nor Ubuntu knew what to do with it.

What is the easiest way to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 10 is also called Lucid, not Karmic as Dennis put in his example, so put the following to your /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
```

Run:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install acroread
```

Comment: Oops. That's what I get for blindly pasting from my system.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install acroread
```

**Edit:**

You'll need to uncomment the following line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` first:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
```

Just edit that file and remove the `#` at the beginning of the line.

Comment: I still get `E: couldn't find package acroread`.

Comment: @Farmboy: Sorry, I blindly pasted a line from a karmic system. I've corrected that in my answer. You'll probably need to do an `apt-get update` as [patate](http://superuser.com/questions/164259/how-do-i-install-adobe-reader-9-on-ubuntu-10/164437#164437) pointed out. Thanks to **patate** for pointing out my error.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a deb from http://get.adobe.com/reader/, double-click it and press the `Install package` button. Also you can use the command line `sudo dpkg -i the_file_you_downloaded.deb`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying the application manager?Go to applications(on the left top of your screen), then click application manager, and there you can install almost everything without even having to visit the website or anything. Just type reader, pdf or something and it will come up with adobe reader and probably some other programs that do the exact same thing.Application manager is always good place to start...